# Set a specific sidebar width in Bootstrap dashboard template example

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm using the dashboard template example that comes with Bootstrap. Sidebar disappears after a certain screen size and that's fine. But I want to set a specific width until that point. Now it's kind of responsive and stretches in width on bigger screens (it's a bit nasty on large monitors.) A good width would be `250px`.

**CSS**

```
/*
 * Base structure
 */

/* Move down content because we have a fixed navbar that is 50px tall */
body {
  padding-top: 50px;
}


/*
 * Global add-ons
 */

.sub-header {
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;
}


/*
 * Sidebar
 */

/* Hide for mobile, show later */
.sidebar {
  display: none;
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .sidebar {
    position: fixed;
    top: 51px;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 1000;
    display: block;
    padding: 20px;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: auto; /* Scrollable contents if viewport is shorter than content. */
    background-color: #31373d;
    border-right: 1px solid #eee;
  }
}

/* Sidebar navigation */
.nav-sidebar {
  margin-right: -21px; /* 20px padding + 1px border */
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  margin-left: -20px;
}
.nav-sidebar > li > a {
  padding-right: 20px;
  padding-left: 20px;
  color: #98a7b5;
}

.nav-sidebar > li > a:hover {
    background: transparent;
    color: #fff;
}

.nav-sidebar > .active > a, .nav-sidebar > li > a:hover {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #272c30;
}


/*
 * Main content
 */

.main {
  padding: 20px;
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .main {
    padding-right: 40px;
    padding-left: 40px;
  }
}
.main .page-header {
  margin-top: 0;
}


/*
 * Placeholder dashboard ideas
 */

.placeholders {
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  text-align: center;
}
.placeholders h4 {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
.placeholder {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.placeholder img {
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

Any ideas? Thanks.
Source code is avaliable at [getbootstrap.com](http://getbootstrap.com)

Answer (score 0):

How about a `max-width: 250px` in your `.sidebar` CSS?

Comment: Tried and it works, BUT makes a huge space between main content and the sidebar. Solution?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a CSS media query to set a max-width on larger screens..

```
@media (min-width: 992px){
 .sidebar {
   max-width:250px;
 }
}
```

Demo: http://www.bootply.com/126485

Comment: It works, but as you see it creates a huge space between the sidebar and main content. Do you have a fix for that? I forgot to mention it in my question.

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into the same issue. For me I was happy for the sidebar to remain fluid for the small and medium viewports. At a large viewport of 1200px or more I want to have a fixed width of 250px and then have the main content area cover the rest.

In the HTML give your main content div a class name or id. This will make it easy to select it in your css media query. Here i've used a class called `'content'`.

```
<div class="col-sm-3 sidebar"> ...  </div>
<div class="col-sm-9 col-sm-offset-3 content"> ... </div>
```

Then add your css:

```
@media(min-width:1200px){ // breakpoint where I set a fixed sidebar width. You can change this to whatever you want.
  .sidebar {width:250px}
  .content {margin-left:0;padding-left:265px;width:100%;} // reset the width and margin, overwriting the bootstrap grid. Add padding to the left to equal the width of your fixed width sidebar + half your defined grid gutter width. For me that is the default 15px.
}
```